# React Router v4.0.0-beta.7

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to ask about, how to pass parameters by url in React-Router-Dom in beta7. Normally i pass params by Button/Link, next get it in URL and finally catch in match.params object. How to do it in beta7 because i still have no data in my component.

Router definition:

```
<Route path='/users/:_id/edit' component={UsersEdit}/>
```

How I pass params:

```
<Button size='small' as={Link} to={`/users/${_id}/edit`} content='Edit'/>
```

my url:

```
url: "/users/8aTwvLKcWiXopSj2e/edit"
```

params: nothing.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjUp4.png

Comment: Most likely it is a bug, because you are using it as defined in documentation here https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v4/packages/react-router/docs/api/match.md

Comment: Can you show more code? Hard to tell what's really going on with that little of code.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Just anchor a function to a button, and pass params like this:

```
 editUser: ({}, user,) => {
     push(`/users/${user.id}/edit`, {userId: user.id})
 }
```

then in `location.state` (in redirected component) you will be have a parameter for my example `userId`